# MySQL query to select valid domains from a table

Tags: mysql, regex

Simple table domains:
int id, varchar name

table must contain valid domains (we'll consider that domain is valid if it's in form
`.*\.[\w\d_-]{2,3}`

We don't need to validate against DNS of course. 
Running that SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM domain WHERE name NOT REGEXP '.*\.[\w\d_-]{2,3}'
```

returns me some unpredictable result (domains which to me absolutely meets the condition)

example:

```
95323   vandtech.dk
95324   vanee.demon.co.uk
95325   vanens.com
95326   vanger.nl
95327   vangstein.no
95328   vanhoorn-kiel.de
95329   vanityeventi.com
95330   vanloosen.de
```

but does not return invalid entries such as:

```
1.396.041   _.
1.396.042   _.75
1.396.043   _.ca
1.396.044   _23.com
```

Could someone explan me what I'm doing wrong with regexp?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a Perl-style regex, but MySQL doesn't understand those. You can replace, for example, `\d` with `[:digit:]`. Check out [§11.4.2 of the MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your regex would look like:

```
.*\.[[:alnum:][:digit:]_-]{2,3}
```

though to be honest, I think there is some overlap between the various classes. Maybe it could be represented more simply:

```
.*\.[[:alnum:]_-]{2,3}
```

I should point out, too, that the underscore `_` is not valid in any part of a domain name.

Comment: >>>I should point out, too, that the underscore _ is not valid in any part of a domain name. 

Thanks for that remark, you're indeed right.